# How to stop class level timer ? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, timer, closures

Today I am reading "Strong Reference Cycles for Closures" from swift programming guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48), and my problem is based on that.

I have two view controllers embedded in a navigation controller, I have nothing in first view controller just use to segue to secondviewcontroller and I have below code in secondViewcontroller aka ViewController2.

> Code 1 :

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (_) in
            print("timer")
        }

    }

}
```

After pop to first view controller, this timer will not end and It will continuously print "timer". How to stop this ?, below is screen shot of Debug memory graph.

[image]

as per above image we can see there is no instance of second view controller, but timer will execute continuously!

If I hold or use strong ref of self in timer closure then I believe it's ok. But as per above code I am not holding or using any strong ref and it also shows in Debug memory graph(there is no ref of secondviewcontroller after pop).

If I use below code then I accept timer is running because of Strong ref cycle as per below code.

> Code 2 :

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (_) in
            print("\(self.view.tag)")
        }

    }

}
```

and below is it's Debug memory graph, after pop to first view controller and one can see **second view controller ref is still live**.

[image]

As per my Code 2 part, I can accept okk it is running because of viewcontroller2 is still in memory and running. But in my Code 1 part there is no sign of viewcontrller2 is in memory and it's timer works ? why ? **how to stop this without making it timer as instance.**

Comment: Whats the question here ? U wanna know why is there a reference of secondVC left in memory in second code why not in first ? or all u need to know is how to stop time when u pop to First VC?

Comment: yes, how to stop time when u pop to First VC

Comment: Are you sure you have popped back to the first VC properly? Are you sure you are not pushing another, new, VC1 onto navigation stack? Because in the last picture, it shows that VC2 is still retained by the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: My question is on Code 1 part, i am showing code 2 part for ref purpose ( what I accept)

Comment: When you use code 1, look at what is retaining `ViewController2`. Is the `UINavigationController` still retaining it?

Comment: As per code 1, no viewcontroller2 is not retained as per first image, but timer of viewcontroller2 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop timer before your SecondVC gets popped out

You need instance variable

```
var timer : Timer;

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if timer != nil && self.isMovingFromParentViewController {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Ok that I accept, but why xcode not showing it in memory graph. As
>   there is no instance of viewcontroller2.

So basically your problem is u wanna know why there is no ViewController2 reference in ur first code and why there is a ViewController2 reference when u use second code in your memory graph :)

**What are blocks?**

In order to understand it u must understand the concept of blocks/closure.
Blocks/Closures are nothing more than a reference counted Object like structure in heap memory.

When you pass the blocks as a parameter you pass this object in heap from one function to another.

These are reference counted objects so all the rules of ARC applies to them as well.

**Context Capturing**

The only reason why Closures are different from other contemporary parts of it (instance and static method) is ContextCapturing. Blocks are capable of capturing the variables that are declared out side its contexts while instance and static methods cant.

**What is Context Capturing?**

Every time compiler sees the syntax of closure/block it copies all the code in Closure to a object in heap. Along with that it copies all the variables that are accessed inside it. Thats the reason closure is capable of accessing the variables that are declared out side its scope.

**Why are u telling me all this ?**

In your code

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (_) in
        print("\(self.view.tag)")
    }
```

When u access self inside closure, the your Second VC gets copied to closure object in heap memory. Because its a strong reference reference count of your Second VC gets incremented by +1.

Hence when you tap back button Second VC is not deallocated because ARC removes object only when its reference count is 0.

while in your code

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (_) in
        print("timer")
    }
```

U haven't accessed self so when your SecondVC refrence count is never changed from its original value. Hence when u tap back button deist gets called on Second VC

Thats why u don't see reference of second VC in first code where as u see it in Second Code.

Why do u see rerferece of Timer is already explained by Sweeper in his answer :) No point in explaining again

Comment: I have also asked "how to stop this without making it global", you can find in my question

Comment: @anand-suthar : You seriously need to work on your coding Jargons buddy. I haven't made timer global its a instance variable. It becomes global when I declare it as static and Access it as SecondVC.timer

Comment: invalidate() is a instance method declared on Timer. There is no static method in Timer class to invalidate all timers.

Comment: ok, but I don't want to make an instance. I want to use as Class level function. (Head less)

Comment: @anand-suthar : Timer does not have any static method to cancel the timer buddy :) invalidate is only a instance method :) Unless u write ur own timer class u cant do it :) So basically u cant

Comment: Ok that I accept, but why xcode not showing it in memory graph. As there is no instance of viewcontroller2.

Comment: @anand-suthar : Looks like u messed up the Blocks/closures concept. Lemme update my answer hope it makes clear

Comment: @anand-suthar : Please read the updated answer. Hope it helps u understand the concept of blocks/closures

Comment: Thanks a lot you correctly understand what I am asking for, you answer help me a lot. But that means never call a class level method because it will never be released as I am calling Timer's class level method and there is no way to release those memory :)

Comment: @anand-suthar : "never call a class level method" that depends buddy as Sweeper explained you were calling Timer which was added to CFRunLoop thats why it was running forever. But assume u have a method to add two number on class level calling such method won't leave the object in memory forever. Basically when u call a method once the control goes out of scope it will purged because timer is meant to run forever it was running. So be careful of what u call and what not. Don't be under impression that u can never call class method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete the timer from memory by making the timer a class-level variable and calling `invalidate` on it in `viewDidDisappear` or methods like that.

The way timers work, is that when you schedule a timer, a `CFTimer` is added to a `CFRunLoop`, and something called an `NSTimerBlockTarget` gets created. You can see this from the memory graph:

[image]

As long as the `CFTimer` is alive, the timer won't stop. When you call `invalidate`, it will remove the timer from the run loop.